# React netlify 404 error navigating back to portfolio

Tags: reactjs, web, react-router, netlify

**Background**

I'm making a portfolio website in React and it is hosted through Netlify. All the websites I have created use React and React Router and are hosted through Netlify

I have four external links on my portfolio:

1. LinkedIn profile
2. Github profile
3. Another website I built called Shoppies
4. Another website I built called GithubFinder

**Problem**
When I click links 3 and 4 and then hit the back button in my browser, I sometimes get a 404. This never happens with the first two links and there doesn't seem to be a  pattern for when the error does happen.

Here's a link to  [my website](https://www.katecookwebdev.com/)

And a screenshot of the error I get[error message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/786Ag.png)

Thanks in advance for the help I really appreciate it!

Comment: I don't get 404 at your website

Comment: You can try this solution. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58432771/15497939)